# Ansible common vars for roles

Tags: variables, ansible

I hope someone can help me, i am trying to use common vars for all roles in my playbook.
For example, within roles, I have "inf_role1", "inf_role2", "inf_role3" and would like here to place folder (if possible) "common", where would be vars, handlers for all roles. I have tried this combination and vars are not executed.
I am trying to avoid group_vars and hosts_vars, so only interested within roles.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a common role, e.g. `inf_role0`, which would have all the common definitions. To call this new common role from the other ones you could declare it as a dependency in the `meta/main.yml` file on each of the other roles.

`meta/main.yml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  - inf_role0
```

More information on the [Running role dependencies multiple times in one play](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#running-role-dependencies-multiple-times-in-one-play) section of the [Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html) user guide.

Answer (score 0):

This work just as i needed, thanks for this.
I have also included in dependecies: - roles: role_name so i can connect roles between themselves which is also good.
Thanks again Antonio!